# Getting data from a csv file only of a particular country

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning

I have a csv file that I'm working with in python using pandas library. This csv file has column like country, height, weight etc.
I want get a list of weight of a particular country say USA.
Is there a easy way to do this using pandas.

Comment: It seems like a duplicate that questions answer is hard for me to understand. Can I get a way probably a full code to show how this is done

Comment: Maybe, if we get a full question with your data in text form, expected output, and any associated code and traceback errors. We reward _good_ questions with answers. See [ask].